# Database cross table or one table is better

Tags: sql, database-design, crosstab

First, I have companies and their templates.templates in file table I related columns like this:

```
FileTemplate 
-------------------
ID -  CompanyID - Description  -  FileID
```

Second design:

```
FileTemplate            
-------------------
ID  -   Description
```

CrossTable:

```
                        
-----------------------------------------      
ID  - CompanyID -  FileID  -  FileTemplateID
```

Which design is better for performance and maintenance? There will be a lot of data (1 million rows).  It will be a very active table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, the second approach is better as you have a huge amount of data. Normalizing is always the best approach. As you said, there should be company and field tables seperately along with the cross reference table.

Hope this is of some help for you!!

Comment: +1 - Normalizing is _usually_ the way to go, yes.  This of course assumes that the values in `description` (and any other related fields) are not unique, and will benefit from the extraction/deduplication.  Given the context I think that likely (but it was not explicitly spelled out in the question).

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually we made simple one table for this job. But after decided to put description column. There for i confused to use normalize system "for one description column" or use just one table for escape complex situation.